# How to use 2 or more databases with spring (xml configuration)

Tags: java, spring-data

I'm new in spring and trying to switch between 2 different DBs. I've made these changes in spring configuration xml file:

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:config/db-config.properties" />
    </bean>

    <!-- MS Sql DB -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    </bean>
    <!-- end -->

    <!-- MySql DB -->
    <bean id="dataSourceMySql"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver1}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url1}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username1}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password1}" />
    </bean>
    <!-- end -->

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.epam.model" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"></prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
        </property>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryMySql"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.epam.model" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMySql" />

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"></prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
        </property>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManagerMySql" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryMySql" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerMySql" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.epam.repository" />

</beans>
```

what I need to add in repository or service to specify which db I want to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for responce. I'm just added 2nd db specific key/values in properties file and depending on the db type, just uncommented appropriate ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the second data source using @Resource annotation

Comment: I've added @Resource in JobServiceImpl, but get exceptions. Do I need to add it anywhere else?

Comment: that should work.. What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryMySql' defined in class path resource [config/spring/database.xml]: